# Using querySelector to target row in specific table by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are three tables with id table1, table2, and table3. I have one delete button in a modal that I want to use to selectively target a row in a table (to delete or edit).

The modal has 2 hidden inputs, one for the row and one for the table:

```
<input type="hidden" id="row_num" value=""/><input type="hidden" id="table_num" value=""/>
```

I have the following code to pass the variables to the modal:

```
 function (e){
        // get the parent table row
        row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        // get the parent table
        table = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    ...
        // pass table row ID to the modal
         document.getElementById('row_num').value = row.getAttribute('id');
        // pass table ID to the modal
        document.getElementById('table_num').value = table.getAttribute('id');
}
```

I'm not sure how to use these variables to write the functions though. For example, this is the code I'm trying to use to delete a specific row in a specific table:

```
$('.modal-action').on('click', function(){
        table_id= document.getElementById('table_num').value;
        row_id = document.getElementById('row_num').value;
       document.getElementById(row_id).remove();
}
```

I tried using querySelector in various forms but kept getting an error. What is the correct way to target the specific row in the specific table by ID?

Comment: Show the html of the table, the row and its data, and example of what you want to do to it.

Comment: the ```id``` property must be unique on a page. So it's usual to give the rows ids like 't1_r1', 't1_r2', ... ,'t2_r1', 't2_r2, ....

Comment: Okay, makes sense. I'm using the following js to add new rows: `table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='acc_row"+table_len+"'>...` So, could I just add the table id via a variable?